# pickerview issue

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have 2 segment UIPickerView
one is having number and second "Quantity"

Both segment has None as their first index.

what i m trying to do is, whenever i choose None(first element) from an of the segment,
the respective, first element of the other segment should also move to None(which is first element,automatically.)
Makes sense??

Guidance needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, here's the code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (row == 0) {
        [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:((component+1)%1) animated:YES];
    }
}
```